# New Folder Error - Read Only File System in File Explorer

Tags: android

I am trying to create a folder within sdcard folder like: **/mnt/sdcard/eventImages/** but every time getting New Folder Error - Read Only file system.

I am working on Windows XP

Code:

```
    private List <String> getSD()
    {
        List <String> it = new ArrayList <String>();
        File f = new File ("/mnt/sdcard/mydata/");
        File[] files = f.listFiles ();

        for (int i = 0; i <files.length; i++)
        {
            File  file = files[i];
            Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
            it.add (file.getPath());
        }
        return it;
    }
```

Comment: try getExternalStorageDirectory and friends... maybe your device does not have the sdcard at /mnt/sdcard but somewhere else? This is a mess in Android, unfortunately.

Comment: @jeevamuthu i have posted my code

Comment: did you solve this issue..

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you have the required permission for that

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

> Code to check and create Directory if it does not exists

```
 private void _dirChecker(String dir) { 

        File f = new File(dir); 

        if(!f.isDirectory()) { 
          f.mkdirs(); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this one...

       File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/eventImages/");

    if (!direct.exists()) 
    {
        direct.mkdir();
    }
```

and put this permission

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```